# How to use mod_rewrite when files are in subdir and pass on a id?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, web, url-rewriting

Have this url: http://example.com/index.php?sideID=subpage/mypage&id=22

want this url: http://example.com/mypage/20

the file subpage is placed inside www/sybpage/mypage.php and is curently needing the id to work correctly.

Im trying with:

```
#RewriteRule ^([\w!-]+)/([\w!-]+/[^/]+/[\w!-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ index.php?sideID=$1&subpage=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

I also want to add if the file mypage.php are moved into root dir and i use this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-åA-Å0-9_!-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?sideID=$1&currentpage=$2 [L,QSA]
```

it will work as i want it, but i want mypage.php files to be moved in to a own folder.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your regex is correctly matching, and this htaccess file is inside of www/ , you should just change your target to : subpage/index.php?sideID=$1&subpage=$2

Comment: Have you checked your logs? It should tell you the exact file you're trying to read after the rewrite. Also where is your htaccess file? That should also tell you if your expression is matching.

Comment: Not 100% sure where to find that log, and not sure if the reg-ex is correct as well. But the file is inside another folder inside the main root. htacces is also placed in mainroot.

Comment: Do a google search for your apache log on your OS. It's in different places based on your OS and what method you used to install it. For example cpanel/centos keeps it in a different place from ubuntu/apt and windows/xampp. you want to find the error log

Comment: path not found, is the error, i have updateed the question if somone have idea how to make proper regex